# How to hide or protect auth credentials in interactions with an LRS

Tags: javascript, tin-can-api

I'm using xapiwrapper.min.js and files like it to send statements to an LRS. My own file containing javascript is called init.js and is shown below. Init.js is referenced from my other main html5 files. As you look further down in my init.js file you will see some credentialing information for the ADL LRS. Is there any way to keep this from being able to be viewed by the user?

init.js file

```
<!--This happens when the user clicks the Submit button.-->
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    //creating a couple of local variables
    var name = $("#nameID").val();
    var email = $("#emailID").val();

    if(name=='') {
    alert("Please enter a name");
    myForm.name.focus();
    return (false);
    }
    if(email=='') {
    alert("Please enter an email");
    myForm.name.focus();
    return (false);
    }

    //creating global variables
    setGlobal(email, name);
    //move to page 2
    document.location.replace("tableOfContents.html");

});



//Setting some global variables in case we need them later.
function setGlobal(actEmail, actName) {
    // Save the name in localStorage.
    localStorage.setItem('name', actName);
    // Save the email in localStorage.
    localStorage.setItem('email', actEmail);
}


<!--When the user clicks the feedback link-->
$("#feedback").click(function(){ 
    window.open('mailto:internaltraining@syniverse.com?subject=Feedback on MS Office 365 tutorials'); 
    });


<!--When the user clicks the logout link-->
 $("#logout").click(function(){ 
    localStorage.removeItem("name");
    localStorage.removeItem("email");
    document.location.replace("index.html");
});



    // Auth for the ADL LRS
    var conf = {
        "endpoint" : "https://lrs.adlnet.gov/xapi/",
        "user": "xapi-tools",
        "password": "xapi-tools",
        "auth": "xapi-tools"
    };




$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#myModal iframe").attr("src", $("#myModal iframe").attr("src"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, no.

The only real way to get around this issue is to use per user credentials in the LRS and have the user "know" their own credentials so that they can enter them when first communicating with the LRS.

Various alternatives exist to improve the situation to various degrees:

1) Use OAuth to make the above suggestion "easier" in so far as OAuth is ever easier. This requires a good understanding of how OAuth works and an LRS that has implemented it and I don't know whether the ADL xAPI wrapper has support for it.

2) Use server side communication with the LRS, this can be done either through a proxy setup such that a server can authenticate and then adjust the credentials of the calls to the LRS or using customized calls that are translated into xAPI calls. In the proxy case it is important that the middle server still does proper authentication of the end user's credentials.

3) Use expirable, limited credentials for instance in a launch scenario so each launch is given a new credential that has limited access to the LRS. This is how the original Tin Can launch guidelines work. (The credential is still available in the client.)

4) Use single use retrieval of expirable, limited credentials for instance in a launch scenario such as how cmi5 is specified. In this case the session is initiated with a fetch URL which can only be accessed once and provides the credential back to the client that has restricted capability. (The credential is still available in the client.)

5) Customize the LRS to allow some other form of authentication.

Other than in #2 ultimately the client will always have a credential to the LRS.

Comment: Should be, 

1) Use OAuth to make the above suggestion "easier" in so far as OAuth is __never__ easier.


Wouldn't let me edit one character :(